# How to change priority of process in powershell, if it runs with -Wait parameter?

Tags: powershell, wait, start-process

I am using a scheduled PowerShell script to start the same process with various arguments many times in a loop. Process is very heavy on computations and runs for a long time, and I have thousands of iterations. I noticed, that since it's a scheduled script, it runs with BelowNormal priority. And even if I bump it, any spawned processes are still BelowNormal. So, since I run this process in a loop thousands of times, I need to use `-Wait` like this:

```
foreach($list in $lists){

        Start-Process -FilePath $path_to_EXE -ArgumentList $list -NoNewWindow -Wait

}
```

Now, I want to bump the priority, and one way I found was to do this:

```
($MyProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $path_to_EXE -ArgumentList $list  -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
```

However, it doesn't work, because it needs to wait until process finishes, then execute whatever is outside of parenthesis: `(...).PriorityClass = ...`
I can't let it proceed with the loop and spawn thousands of processes, I need to run one at a time, but how do I tell it to bump the priority, and then wait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the act of waiting within your code, by way of [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process):

```
foreach($list in $lists) {
    $MyProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $path_to_EXE -ArgumentList $list  -NoNewWindow -PassThru
    $MyProcess.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
    $Myprocess | Wait-Process
}
```

The object returned from `Start-Process` also has a `.WaitForExit()` method:

```
foreach($list in $lists) {
    $MyProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $path_to_EXE -ArgumentList $list  -NoNewWindow -PassThru
    $MyProcess.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
    $Myprocess.WaitForExit()
}
```

Comment: yeah, this works. Thanks!
I tried through 
```$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo``` and 
```$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
            $p.Start() | Out-Null
            $p.WaitForExit()
```
but it didn't work

Comment: @miguello You could also use `$MyProcess.WaitForExit()` with the output from `Start-Process`, rather than having to make an additional call. It also has a `.HasExited` property, but it's better not to do your own looping and polling unless you had to do some other action while you wait.